# Why does xlim cut off border values of continuous scale?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axis-labels

Given data frame:

```
d = structure(list(bin_start = 1:12, 
                   bin_count = c(12892838L, 1921261L, 438219L, 126650L, 41285L, 
                                 15948L, 6754L, 3274L, 1750L, 992L, 703L, 503L)), 
              .Names = c("bin_start", "bin_count"), 
              class = "data.frame", 
              row.names = c(NA, 12L))
```

I can build histogram with `stat="identity"`:

```
ggplot(d) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=bin_start, y=bin_count), stat="identity", 
                 colour="black", fill="white") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:12)
```

that looks like this:

[image]

Not being happy with long tail I limit x scale (equivalent to `xlim=c(1,6)`):

```
ggplot(d) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=bin_start, y=bin_count), stat="identity", colour="black", fill="white") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:12, limits=c(1,6))
```

but I get border points `x=1` and `x=6` disappear:

[image]

Note, that y axis still scales like border points belong to the plot aesthetics. Is it a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A side effect of a feature. Since you've binned the data yourself, you probably want a discrete scale, and a factor for `x`:

```
ggplot(d) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x=factor(bin_start), y=bin_count), stat="identity", colour="black", fill="white") +
    scale_x_discrete(limit=as.character(1:6))
```

[image]

Comment: tried `scale_x_discrete(limit=3:6)` and I still get bars for x=1,2 appear but without labels...

Comment: Try `as.character(3:6)`. For a discrete scale, `limits` is really supposed to be a character vector. I'll modify my answer.